# how to send dynamic json key/value as request params

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    j := `{"url":"http://localhost/test/take-request", "params":{"name":"John","age":"20"},"type":"get"}`
    // k := `{"url":"http://localhost/test/take-request", "params":{"gender":"m","a":"20"},"type":"post"}`

    request := map[string]interface{}{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &request)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(request)
    requestType = strings.ToUpper(request["type"]);
    requestUrl = request["url"];

    fmt.Println(request["params"])

    // how do i get the keys and their values from params.
    // note params is dynamic.
    for _, v := range request["params"].(map[string]interface{}) {
        // println(v)

        switch t := v.(type) {
        case string, []int:
            fmt.Println(t)
        default:
            fmt.Println("wrong type")
        }
    }

    sendRequest(requestType, requestUrl)
}

func sendRequest(type string, url string) string {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(type, url, nil)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
    return string(body)
}
```

1. How do I iterate through params that is an `interface`
2. how do i get the key and its values

Comment: Why use `interface` instead of something more specific?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), JSON objects will be unmarshalled into a `map[string]interface{}` in your case. So you could just add another `case` to your `switch` for that and then just iterate over it like any other map.

Comment: @Flimzy as json contains dynamic key/values in params.

Comment: @Rafee That's not true, though. You seem to know enough about your JSON structure to handle it with type assertions. This means you know enough to define a struct, too--at least for the fields you're dealing with in this function.

Comment: The two JSON strings in your example are also anything but dynamic. They're both very normalized.

Comment: I can only define a struct but not sure with params. as I am going to create a generic adapter (to send the request). `url` and `type` are known but I am not pretty sure about the `params`

Comment: If you need to use `interface{}` for the param values, that's fine. But that's no reason to use it for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code by using a proper struct for your JSON unmarshaling:

```
type Request struct {
    URL    string                 `json:"url"`
    Params map[string]interface{} `json:"params"`
    Type   string                 `json:"type"`
}
```

Then you can unmarshal it more simply as so:

```
request := &Request{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &request); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

And access the values as such:

```
requestType = request.Type
requestURL = request.URL
for key, value := range request.Params {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case float64:
         // handle numbers
    case string:
         // handle strings
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error when one of the parameters in params is integer type.

Comment: @Rafee: Then you do need to use `interface{}` for the param values, and a type switch probably.